# Is there a ¨periodic table¨ for numbers?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Is there a best way to organize numbers so that it identifies the most traits within each number?

(edit for clarification): a multiplication table gives simple detail to help understand multiples and divisors. Is there a more dynamic table that gives more detail to each number?

For instance, a multiplication table with only primes on the axis or maybe a slide rule could be argued to be an organization of numbers that gives a lot of insight.

Comment: Even as a soft question this is too vague.  Could you try explaining what you want a tad better?  Probably need to be more specific as to which traits you are interested in.

Comment: This is far too broad.

Comment: It is a very good question. Math is abstract arts and science that deal with abstract and vague questions. I believe by finding such periodic table will help us understand special numbers such as primes better.

Comment: The elements of the "periodic table" are the prime numbers. Those are the "atoms". Non-prime integers are "molecules".

Comment: To shed some more light on my definition of organizing numbers. A multiplication table organizes numbers so that it is very easy to identify a couple simple traits. Are there more dynamic tables that explain numbers in much more detail. Is there one that explains more than all others?

Comment: I recommend you the slides by Matilde Marcolli, *Geometry and Physics of Numbers*. (Caltech) Revolution Books, Berkeley, May 2013. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your questions is: no, there isn't a periodic table of numbers.

However, there a certainly many numbers that share similar properties. But it is hard to organize this when one hasn't established what properties your are interested in.

However since all natural numbers have a unique decomposition into a product of prime numbers, prime numbers could be thought of as building blocks of the whole numbers. As such many "properties" of numbers can be answered in terms of prime numbers. In fact the study of prime numbers has for a long time fascinated mathematicians (and non-mathematicians). There are still many unanswered questions relating to prime numbers. My point is that one approach to a "periodic table" of numbers could focus on prime numbers.

Comment: Why the downvote

Comment: I suspect the downvote occurred when someone wanted to disparage the Question.  Your Answer is not bad, certainly better than the string of links in the Answer below.  If the Questioni were reopened, I'd be tempted to say something about [arithmetic dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics).

Answer (score -1):

There have been a few sites that attempt to organize numbers by their qualities. See what you think of each of the following approaches:

[What's Special About This Number?](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/numbers.html)

[Number Gossip](http://www.numbergossip.com/)

[The Secret Lives of Numbers](http://turbulence.org/Works/nums/)

[Notable Properties of Specific Numbers](http://www.mrob.com/pub/math/numbers.html)

[Zoo of Numbers](http://www.archimedes-lab.org/numbers/Num1_69.html)

[The Database of Number Correlations: Properties and Meanings](http://www.virtuescience.com/number.html)

[Wikipedia's Integers Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integers)

[Prime Curios](http://primes.utm.edu/curios/index.php)

[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/)

Comment: I am asking for best ways to organize numbers, not how to look them up.

Comment: Maybe the Congruence classes of numbers modulo a natural number. You will get a Cayley table that looks like a "periodic table".

Comment: If these sites do "attempt to organize number by their qualities," you should present not just bare links but a summary of their distinctive approaches.  In fact most of these links are mere catalogs of interesting facts about particular integers.  Please revise your Answer if you still take an interest in it.